Proof of random-self-reucibility of LWE (worst- to average-case) in Regev paper, Lemma 4.1
I'm reading proof of [Regev'arXive2401.03703, lemma 4.1, page 30].

I can't figure out how Oded Regev estimates acceptance probability of the average-case distinguisher by Chernoff bound


Thorem (Chernoff bound [Michel Goenams, MIT, Lecure note]) Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$, where $X_{i}=1$ with probability $p_{i}$ and $X_{i}=0$ with probability $1−p_{i}$, and all $X_{i}$ are independent. Let $\mu=E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}$: Then
$$\Pr[|X-\mu|\geq\delta\mu]\leq2e^{-\mu\delta^{2}/3}, \ \text{for all}\ 0<\delta<1$$


Also, isn't it worst-case to average-case? Why has Oded Regev written average-case to worst-case?!

Here is the proof:

Notations: $A_{\mathbf{s},\chi}$: the distribution on $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ obtained by choosing a vector $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}$ uniformly at random, choosing $e\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ according to $\chi$, and outputting $(\mathbf{a},\langle\mathbf{a},\mathbf{s}\rangle+e\mod p)$. $U$: uniform distribution on $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, We say that an algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ with oracle access is a distinguisher between two distributions if its acceptance probability when the oracle outputs samples of the first distribution and its acceptance probability when the oracle outputs samples of the second distribution differ by a non-negligible amount.


Lemma 4.1 (Average-case to Worst-case) Let $n,p\geq1$ be some integers and $\chi$ be some distribution on $\mathbb{Z}p$. Assume that we have access to a distinguisher $W$ that distinguishes $A_{\mathbf{s},\chi}$ from $U$ for a non-negligible fraction of all possible $\mathbf{s}\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. Then there exists an efficient algorithm $W'$ that for all $\mathbf{s}\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ accepts with probability exponentially close to $1$ on inputs from $A_{\mathbf{s},\chi}$ and rejects with probability exponentially close to $1$ on inputs from $U$.


Proof: ($\color{blue}{\text{Main idea}}$ (Vinod Vaikuntnathan's Lecture note 2015): introducing random-self-reduction map) The proof is based on the following transformation. For any $\mathbf{t}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}$ consider the function $f_{\mathbf{t}}:\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ defined by
$$f_{\mathbf{t}}(\mathbf{a},b)=(\mathbf{a},b+\langle\mathbf{a},\mathbf{t}\rangle).$$
It is easy to see that this function transforms the distribution $A_{\mathbf{s},\chi}$ into $A_{\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{t},\chi}$. Moreover, it transforms the uniform distribution $U$ into itself.


($\color{blue}{\text{Random self reduction}}$ (like proof of theorem 10.3 of Boneh-Shoup book)) Assume that for $n^{−c_{1}}$ of all possible $\mathbf{s}$, the acceptance probability of $W$ on inputs from $A_{\mathbf{s},\chi}$ and on inputs from $U$ differ by at least $n^{−c_{2}}$. We construct $W'$ as follows.


Let $R$ denote the unknown input distribution. Repeat the following $n^{c_{1}+1}$ times. Choose a vector $\mathbf{t}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}$ uniformly at random. Then
$\color{red}{\text{estimate the acceptance probability}}$ of $W$ on $U$ and on $f_{\mathbf{t}}(R)$ by calling $W$ $\mathcal{O}(n^{2c_{2}+1})$ times on each of the input distributions. By the $\color{red}{\text{Chernoff bound}}$, this allows us to obtain an estimate that with probability exponentially close to $1$ is within $\pm n^{−c_{2}/8}$ of the true acceptance probabilities.


If the two estimates differ by more than $n^{−c_{2}/2}$ then we stop and decide to accept. Otherwise we continue. If the procedure ends
without accepting, we reject.


We now prove that $W'$ distinguishes $A_{\mathbf{s},\chi}$ from $U$ for all $\mathbf{s}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}$. First, we claim that when $R$ is $U$, the acceptance probability of $W′$ is exponentially close to $0$. Indeed, in this case, $f_{\mathbf{t}}(U)=U$ and therefore the two estimates that $W′$ performs are of the same distribution. The probability that the estimates differ by more than $n^{−c_{2}/2} > 2\cdot n^{−c_{2}/8}$ is exponentially small. Next, consider the case that $R$ is $A_{\mathbf{s},\chi}$ for some $\mathbf{s}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}$.
In each of the $n^{c_{1}+1}$ iterations, we are considering the distribution $f_{\mathbf{t}}(A_{\mathbf{s},\chi})=A_{\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{t},\chi}$ for some uniformly chosen $\mathbf{t}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{q}$. Notice that the distribution of $\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{t}$ is uniform on $\mathbb{Z}^{n}_{p}$. Hence, with probability exponentially close to $1$, in one of the $n^{c_{1}+1}$ iterations, $\mathbf{t}$ is such that the acceptance probability of $W$ on inputs from $A_{\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{t},\chi}$ and on inputs from $U$ differ by at least $n^{−c_{2}}$. Since our estimates are within $\pm n^{−c_{2}/8}$, $W′$ accepts with probability exponentially to $1$.

